# Open xml file on listview item click

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

I'm trying to open a new xml or text file when the user select an item on listview. Below is my code:
Original Question-->

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.listview;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

When `onListItemClick` is triggered I want to open xml file which has some data.
When "Android" is selected android.xml, shows up.
When "iPhone" is selected iphone.xml, shows up.

Comment: So whats the problem in it??
What are you asking here???

Comment: i'm not sure how to show associated .xml file when item is selected.

Comment: position is the index of list item. so why do you have  `int postion = 0;` remove it and remove String[] values = null;

Comment: i'm getting an error if i dont define it..error --> "values cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: check the edit. that is basic java stuff. values is a string array declared and initialize inside `onCreate`. SO it becomes local to `onCreate`. Make the changes mentioned and read a good book on java

Comment: nevermind there was a typo "postion" should be "position".. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onItemClick`

Follow

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjHYyAJQ7Vw&list=PL3D7BFF1DDBDAAFE5

Which seems to be good tutorial for a start.

You don't open a xml. You navigate to a different activity based on the position of List item click. Each activity will have its own layout set.

The below should work

```
try
{
String val = values[postion];
Class ourClass  = Class.forName("com.example.listview."+val);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ourClass);
startActivity(intent);
}catch(Exception e){
      e.prinStacktrace();
}
```

Make sure you make an entry for `Activities` in manifest file

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
   String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    try
    {
    String val = values[postion];
    Class ourClass  = Class.forName("com.example.listview."+val);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ourClass);
    startActivity(intent);
    }catch(Exception e){
          e.prinStacktrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There will be some issues with class names based on the String[] values he has listed. I might try an if/else if statement instead.

if(val.equals("Mac OS X"){ Intent intent = new Intent(this, MacOSX.class); } ...

Comment: @wblaschko what issues are you talking about??

Comment: "OS/2" for example, would be a poor choice of class names. But it's human-readable, so it needs to stay that way in the ListView.

Comment: @wblaschko poor choice by op. may be. what difference would that make. an that is the choice or correction that op must make

Comment: Exactly, I agree with you general structure and answer, I was just proposing a solution to this particular problem: the if/else based on the value to define the Intent's class.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to discuss hypotheticals here. At that point I would create ONE activity and pass that activity the int id of the XML file I want to display (I might in this situation anyway). No reason to create multiple classes unless each requires its own special methods--it sounds like from this situation like the OP just wants to display information for each.

Comment: @Raghunandan - when i click on android, nothing is happeneing.. i have added my code on the original question.

Comment: `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("layout",R.id.android);
intent.putExtras(bundle);`
For example.

Comment: @wblaschko well my point is entirely different. your comments are based on assumption. With what op posted i have answered.

Answer (score 2):

> `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
>                 int position, long id) {
>                 switch(position){
>                 case 0:
>                     Intent firstIntent = new Intent(AndroidListViewActivity.this, SingleListItem.class);
>                     startActivity(firstIntent);
>                     break;
>
>                 case 1:
>                     Intent secondintent = new Intent(AndroidListViewActivity.this, jokes.class);
>                     startActivity(secondintent);
>                     break;`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumptions mentioned in the conversation on @Raghunandan's answer, here is how I would complete this task. This assumes that each of your different XMLs (Android, iPhone, etc) doesn't require unique functions (there would be ways to do this to an extent using onClicks in the layout), but that the intention is to display information.

This is the class you posted:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayInformation.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        int layout;
        //figure out which layout we want to display based on our human-readable String[]
        if(item.equals("Android")){
            layout=R.id.android;
        }else if(item.equals("iPhone")){
            layout=R.id.iphone;
        }else if{
            ...
        }
        //attach the bundle with the layout to the intent
        bundle.putInt("layout",layout);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        //start our intent
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is the new class I would use to display the information:

```
public class DisplayInformation extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        this.super(icicle);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras.containsKey("layout")){
            setContentView(extras.getInt("layout"));
        }else{
            //we tried to start the activity with no layout defined
            this.finish();
        }

    }
}
```

And the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name= "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".DisplayInformation" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```