# NEW ACTIVITY NOT SHOWING UP

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to make a app in which when i click on the list the new activity should get open up.For example if i click on apple the apple xml file should get open up but it is not happening.

```
package com.example.fruitsinfo;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Home extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{
String fruits[]={"apple","BANANA","MANGO","CHERRY","ORANGE","LITCHE","GRAPES","WATRMELON","KIWI","SWEET LEMON","STAWBERRY","POMOGRANATE"};
Context c=this;
ListView lv;
@Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(c, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fruits);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String location=fruits[arg2];
    try {
        Class a= Class.forName("com.example.fruitsinfo." + location);
        Intent intent=new Intent(c,a);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

Apple.java Class

```
package com.example.fruitsinfo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class apple  extends Activity{
    ImageView apple;
    ScrollView sv;
    TextView tv;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        apple=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Log.d("asfdasf","apple class");
        sv=(ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.SonucScrollView);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.SonucTextView);

    }

}
```

Comment: You dont have any setContentView in your apple Activity..

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941182/open-xml-file-on-listview-item-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the

```
setContentView(R.layout.<youractivitylayout>);
```

in appleActivity. then only it will show image view bcoz content of the layout has no element so try to put this below line in your apple activity..

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.<youractivitylayout>);
```

followed by fetching the your layout elements in your apple Activity.
thank you...

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `setContentVew` in apple Activity. It will crash coz you have not set the content of the layout to the activity and you initialize views before that.

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout); 
 apple=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Also follow java naming conventions. Replace apple by Apple.

Edit:

You have

```
 Context c=this; // remove this
```

Or

Initialize `c` in `onCreate`

Context is not available untill Activity is created.

Also change

```
Class a= Class.forName("com.example.fruitsinfo." + location);
Intent intent=new Intent(c,a);
```

to

```
Class a= Class.forName("com.example.fruitsinfo."+location);
Intent intent=new Intent(Home.this,a);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your **apple** activity class you didn't set your view. so just call this

```
setContentView(R.layout.layoutname);
```

after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can add activity in androidmainfest file and check your package name is correct

You are missing setCotent in apple class so you can add

```
     setContentView(R.layout.apple);
```