# how to start a activity clicking a list item in listactivity class

Tags: java, android

i want start activities based on the list item i click. i created a listactivity class and i have already done the arrayadpter stuff and all but in the i want to start an activity based on the item i clicked. like if the item name is Menu and i click on it, it should start the menuactivity class. same goes for the rest.

i tried this

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
// getting the position and launching the activity associated with it
switch(position){
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuList.class));
break;
default:
break;
}
}
```

All it does is, go blank and return me back to the MainActivity class. somebody help me here. In the list is MenuList, Beverages, drinks and contact and i want when i click on each list item, it launches the activity associated with it

Comment: this looks alright. have you declared the activities in manifest

Comment: post your MenuList.java code

Comment: @Raghunandan I don't think so. If so, there would be error but here is blank and back to MainActivity.java

Comment: @Nabin op must have not set layout to activity and probably called `finish()` in `onCreate` to  return to previous one. yes if activity is not declared in manifest you will get ActivityNotFoundException

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes me too think so. He must have copy pasted the onCreate() method and forgot to change the layout.

Comment: @Raghunandan but we can be sure only if he posts the MenuList.java class

Comment: does the app crash? post `MenuList.java`

Comment: @raghunandan: i didnt do so. i set my layout the way i wanted and my layout shows. all i want is to move to the MenuList class from the MainActivity

Comment: @Andrecon pls post the relevant java files so that we can help further. As far as the code posted now looks alright

Comment: @Andrecon and switch without a case

Comment: @Raghunandan: Will do that. i aint on  my own pc but will get the files and paste

Comment: @Andrecon and do check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941182/open-xml-file-on-listview-item-click

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose the correct Activity based on the clicked item. If you have a static list of items, e.g., `Menu, Beverages, Drinks`, you could write something like this:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    // getting the position and launching the activity associated with it
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuList.class));
        break;
    case 1:
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Beverages.class));
        break;
    case 2:
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Drinks.class));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```