# How to open different activities on a listview with OnItemClickListener?

Tags: android

How can I open different activities after I click on different items on a listview? Like, if I click on item no. 1, it will take me to Activity 1. If I click on item no.2, it will take me to Activity 2.

I've searched on all over stack overflow about this and I've tried all the solutions and how to do it but I can't do it. There's always an error on `ArrayAdapter`.

If someone can explain me nicely it will be a huge help me for me. I've been trying this since last 3 days but I can't do this.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941182/open-xml-file-on-listview-item-click if it helps

Comment: Can you please post your adapter's code and the error log?

Comment: There's an error showing red marks on array adapter

Comment: and what is that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to apply a switch case on the `position` variable of the `onItemClickListener`  of the `Listview`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (position) {
          case 0:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity,this, FirstClass.class);
            break;
          case 1:
            intent = new Intent(MainACtivity.this,SecondClass.class);
            break;

        }
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
```